# How do I do Vue.set() in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

As explained [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api-treeshaking.html#_3-x-syntax), Vue 3 has moved a bunch of functions that were available on the global Vue instance. They are now named imports. This leads me to think I should be able to do `import {set} from 'vue'`, but I can't. It's not there. Where is set()?

Comment: You should not need `set` anymore in vue 3. Where do you find a need to still use `set` ?

Comment: Vue.set is only available in compatibility builds, because the new features in Vue3 means you no longer will run into reactivity issues in Vue2: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api-treeshaking.html#affected-apis. Can you share an MCVE on why Vue.set is needed?

Comment: Yup. In fact it's not needed. I was porting some code and so looking around for it. Great. I can do without it.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### You don't need to.

[This article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/so-what-actually-is-vue-set) will help you to understand why we needed vue.set in the first place. In short, you need it so that you could add a new property to a data object without breaking the reactivity.

With Vue 3, you no longer need to worry about breaking the reactivity. What the article says you shouldn't do in Vue 2, you can now do in Vue 3.

Example on vue 2:

```js
data() {
  return {
    personObject: {
      name: 'John Doe'
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  addBio(bio) {
     this.$set(this.personObject, 'bio', bio)  // this was needed on vue 2
}
```

Now, on Vue 3 you can add the bio property directly to the object and the object will still be reactive:

```js
methods: {
  addBio(bio) {
     this.personObject['bio'] = bio
  }
}
```

Comment: Tip: If you have a good editor (I'm using VSCode), you can use something like the following Regex to replace them:
 Find: Vue.set\((.*?), (.*?), (.*)\)
 Replace: $1[$2] = $3

Comment: @Frank  Thanks for the idea, i had to escape the enclosing parenthesis to make it work though : `Vue.set\((.*?), (.*?), (.*)\)`

Comment: Brilliant @Frank thanks! I had to adapt a bit to `this.\$set\((.*?), (.*?), (.*)\)`.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/05/vue-js-reactivity/) talks about reactivity in vue 2 and 3(composition + options API)

You won't need to because vue 3 now uses proxy detection. If you are using a watch and it is not working use the tag **deep: true**

```
watch: {
    deep: true
    someObject: {
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
         x.x()
      },
      
    }
  }
```

Be aware that **deep true** doesn't have much performance so don't use it on huge objects

Comment: thank you, you saved me 16 hours of time on this issue!!! In my situation I had a vuex store which was an array of objects coming back as a JSON response, and this made it detect the change after the AJAX request overwrote the vuex! Beautiful!