# How can I get the count of Object keys in a Vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to count the number of entries in an object and output that to the user. In a method this works fine using `Object.keys(this.myObject).length` but when outputting that in the template it is always 0.

Example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Selected: {{ selectedCount }}<br> <!-- Always 0 -->
        Selected: {{ Object.keys(selected).length }}<br> <!-- Always 0 -->

        <div class="referral-redemptions-table">
            <b-table 
                ref="table"
                :items="referrals">
                <template v-slot:cell(isReferralRedeemed)="data">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @click="markSelected(data.index)" :class="{ 'btn-ghost' : data.item.isSelected }">
                        {{ data.item.isSelected ? 'Selected' : 'Redeem' }}
                    </button>
                </template>
            </b-table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                referrals: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        isSelected: false,
                        name: 'Test',
                        email: 'test@example.com'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        isSelected: false,
                        name: 'Test',
                        email: 'test@example.com'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        isSelected: false,
                        name: 'Test',
                        email: 'test@example.com'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        isSelected: false,
                        name: 'Test',
                        email: 'test@example.com'
                    },
                ],
                fields: [
                    {
                        key: 'name',
                        label: 'Who',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'email',
                        label: 'Email',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                ],
                selected: {},
            }
        },

        computed: {
            // a computed getter
            selectedCount: function () {
                return Object.keys(this.selected).length;
            }
        },

        methods: {
            // Mark an item as selected
            markSelected: function(index) {
                // Not selected, add it
                if(!this.referrals[index].isSelected) {
                    this.selected[index] = {
                        'id' : this.referrals[index].id, 
                        'email' : this.referrals[index].email
                    };
                } else {
                    delete this.selected[index];
                }

                console.log(Object.keys(this.selected).length); // Outputs the correct number

                this.referrals[index].isSelected = !this.referrals[index].isSelected;
                this.$refs.table.refresh();
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Update**

To add to the confusion, if I set a `data` attribute of `numSelected: 0` and then set this in the `markSelected` method using the `Object.keys` approach then everything works, even `Object.keys(selected).length` is available in the template, not just the variable I'm setting.

```
<!-- In template... -->
Selected: {{ numSelected }}<br> <!-- This now shows correctly... -->
Selected: {{ Object.keys(selected).length }} <!-- But so does this. Why would this not work before? -->

markSelected: function(index) {
    // [...]

    this.numSelected = Object.keys(this.selected).length;

    // [...]
},
```

Comment: Generally such code doesn't belong to a template, so you won't have this problem when it's written in a common way, with computeds or methods.

Comment: @EstusFlask can you explain what you mean please? It's not unreasonable to want to show that to a user, and I am using a computed value, as well as the raw value. Both are not updated. Similarly in the updated example, it only works if I set a variable using the raw method, at which point the raw method also works.

Comment: I mean that writing expressions in template is not a good practice, and one of reasons is that template compiler works in obscure and undocumented way. You may even not have access to all globals there (Object works for some reason, but again, it's not documented).  Another reason is that JS code is written in one place and easy to maintain and debug. Saw the consequences of 'html programming' in Angular too often. Any way, the explanation is what the answer says. Just don't create new object keys in V2 if you care about reactivity, for arbitrary amount of entries use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the Vue 3 version of this but I believe you're running into change detection caveats (Vue doesn't know you're adding a new key to the object, so it does not re-render)

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

**EDIT** Can you clarify if you're on Vue 2 or 3? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442272) says this problem shouldn't affect you in Vue 3

Comment: I'm on Vue 2.5. I'll give `this.$set` a go, as it does sound like that exact issue, especially you take into account the update I've made