# vue, how to show the data of an object which is inside an array

Tags: vue.js

I am getting the decorTypes data which is inside the tabs array in vue js.in the console, the data is showing but in devtools it is not showing. My script's code is

```js
<script type="module">
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tabs: [{
        rate: "",
        selectedHouseType: "",
        decorTypes: {},
      }],

      tabCounter: 0,
      houseTypes: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getHouseTypes() {
      axios.get("/api/houseTypes").then((response) => {
        this.houseTypes = response.data;
        // this.productForm.colors = response.data;
      });
    },
    getDecor() {
      axios.get('/api/decorTypes', {
        params: {
          houseAreaTypeId: this.tabs[this.tabs.length - 1].selectedHouseType
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      **//how to show the data//**
      }.bind(this));
    }

  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are having is a problem in the scope of your function on `.then(function() {...})`. Please, [refer](https://betterprogramming.pub/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256) to this article to understand the difference between arrow function and regular functions

You can get rid of `.bind` and substitute it with an arrow function to have access to the outer scope:

```js
getDecor() {
 axios.get('/api/decorTypes', {
   params: {
     houseAreaTypeId: this.tabs[this.tabs.length - 1].selectedHouseType
   }
 }).then((response) => {
   console.log(response.data);
   // I'm assuming that you want to set `decorTypes` in the last position of the array
   this.tabs[this.tabs.length - 1].decorTypes = response.data;
 });
}
```

### Vue's reactivity system (Vue 2)

The solution above might run into some problems because Vue's reactivity system will not be able to pick up the changes in array. In this case what you are looking for is:

```js
Vue.set(this.tabs[this.tabs.length - 1], 'decorTypes', response.data);
```

[This is not needed in Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442272/4581336)

Comment: not working. in dev tools its showing    decorTypes:Object (empty)

Comment: @rahibd it is really hard to help you if you don't give more context. If you don't give us logs. If you don't give us screenshots after you have tried what we suggested. You need to help us first in order for us to help you

Comment: I am sorry. your method worked later