# Does anyone know how to install the @nuxtjs/composition-api in nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I had a nuxt2 project where the package "@nuxtjs/composition-api" was installed: "^0.33.1",
I need to change nuxt version from 2.5 to 3.6.2, I will be glad if you can help me solve this problem, thanks in advance.

I changed and at the moment I get an error with the yarn dev command

```
 ERROR  error while updating dependencies:                                                                                                                                                                                  4:36:09 PM  
Error: Build failed with 3 errors:
node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api/dist/runtime/index.mjs:1:175: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "set"
node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api/dist/runtime/index.mjs:2:30: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "del"
node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api/dist/runtime/index.mjs:2:409: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "set"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\sky\Web\test\frontend\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1636:15)
    at C:\Users\sky\Web\test\frontend\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1048:25
    at C:\Users\sky\Web\test\frontend\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1512:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

where I don't look I couldn't find the documentation(((, and if i remove the package i get errors in imports
import {onMounted, computed, useRoute, useContext, ref} from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";

Answer (score 1):

I'm also migrating a Nuxt 2 project to Nuxt 3 with the `@nuxtjs/composition-api` package.

One error is that vue 3 deleted the `set` and `del` functions so in order to migrate to 3 you must **replace those with a working solution**.
Remove usage of `Vue.set()` with a compilant Vue 3 reactivity assing.
Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69780482/how-do-i-do-vue-set-in-vue-3) can help!

Then replace all usage of `@nuxtjs/composition-api` with imports from

```js
import { onMounted, computed, ref } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api"; // <-- REMOVE
import { onMounted, computed, ref } from "vue"; // <-- ADD from vue

import { useRoute } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api"; // <-- REMOVE
import { useRoute } from "#imports"; // <-- ADD Path from Nuxt 3


import { useContext } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";
import { useNuxtApp } from "#imports"; // <-- ADD Path from Nuxt 3
```

**Vuex**

Also as bonus if you still use Vuex to handle stores you could use [this package for Nuxt 3](https://github.com/vedmant/nuxt3-vuex), then replace:

```js
import { useStore } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
```

Answer (score 0):

The @nuxtjs/composition-api package backported Composition API functionality to Vue2, however this is no longer require as Nuxt3 is built on top of Vue3; To resolve this issue, you should be able to remove the package from your `package.json` and as a dependency, and use the associated Composition API functions (ref, computed, etc) without requiring any imports, as Nuxt is now handling this via auto-imports, which you can read more about with the below link:

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports

Hope this helps you migrate to Nuxt 3 :)